# Wordpress multisite causing Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error

Tags: apache, php, mod-rewrite, htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WordPress upgrade now receiving Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19446/wordpress-upgrade-now-receiving-error-101-neterr-connection-reset-unknown-e)

We have just installed WordPress 3.0.1 and everything worked fine. However, as soon as we started to install the multisite functionality by following this [tutorial](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network), things started to go wrong. At the end of step 5, the tutorial has you update your wp-config.php file and .htaccess file. Once we made the reccommended changes to these files, uploaded them back to the server and tried to re-log in, none of the pages would serve up anymore. We now get the following error for ALL pages in the blog:

```
Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error.
```

Any ideas? Here are the code changes we made (following the sub-folder setup):

wp-config.php

```
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
$base = '/';
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'oursite.com' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

.htaccces file (in wordpress root directory)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Comment: did you find a fix for this? did it ever work?

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess and wp-config.php look fine.

[Error 101](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Error%20101) is usually caused by a network, router or proxy issue.  It could also be related to your browser cache and or cookies Have you tried connecting with a different browser or computer or clearing your browsers cookies?

It can also be caused by your computers [antivirus or anti phishing software](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=13bd8aa2533edbe3&hl=en) which might not recognize your new site yet.

Was your home url and site url set the same in your general settings?

If they were not you can manually override them in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

I can't thing of anything else it could be.

Comment: sorry, that didn't work - I've restarted this thread here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19446/wordpress-upgrade-now-receiving-error-101-neterr-connection-reset-unknown-er